# iOS - passing data to pushed viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsbundle

When pushing a viewcontroller, how do I pass data long with it as well (such as "asdf":123)? Are you supposed to addObjects to a NSBundle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
MyViewController * myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
myVC.someProperty = someValue;    // Pass your data here
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

And in your `MyViewController` class :

.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * someProperty;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // your data has been set
        // self.someProperty is equal to "some value"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can, but of course you can add relevant properties or methods to your ViewController class and use these prior to pushing it.

Comment: Puzzled by the downvotes, as what I wrote is precisely what the accepted answer does in code...

Answer (score 0):

No. You may be equating `NSBundle` with Android's `Bundle`, but they are not related and do not perform similar tasks. Clafou is correct to suggest passing data via methods and properties.