# Cannot pass value to UIViewController after pusing it using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm able to push a UIViewController through a UITableView controller with the help of a navigation controller(all xibs). Everything works fine but, when I pass the data, the pushed view controller is blank. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here, for example:
    // Create the next view controller.
    PlayerDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[PlayerDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
//    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.title=[self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.myImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    detailViewController.name.text=[self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.year.text=[self.draft objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.height.text=[self.height objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.weight.text=[self.weight objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.pro.text=[self.pro objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.ppg.text=[self.ppg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.apg.text=[self.apg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.rpg.text=[self.rpg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}
```

Comment: Your PlayerDetailsVC has visuals in its xib file? Also, you should not need to use the `initWithNibName:` if the nib and class are the same name. Lastly, generally, you configure the VC before you push it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    PlayerDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[PlayerDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.myImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    detailViewController.name.text=[self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.year.text=[self.draft objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.height.text=[self.height objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.weight.text=[self.weight objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.pro.text=[self.pro objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.ppg.text=[self.ppg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.apg.text=[self.apg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.rpg.text=[self.rpg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.title=[self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting a bunch of similar looking code, it may help to explain what you actually changed. Either beforehand or in code comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use nib but I think you are wrong about implemantation. After pushing from current view to another, objects are gonna release. So here is my advice First create an object to keep your informations then pass it to view controller.

Create a ViewController and init with your object.

Keeping data in an object is the best I think.

Here is code to get idea:

```
//create object that holds your data
YourObject *myObject=[[YourObject alloc] init];
myObject.myImageName=@"image name";
myObject.name=@"name";
//ViewController alloc and push
PlayersDetailViewController *detailView = [[PlayersDetailViewController alloc] initWithObject:myObject];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

And Your object sth like this(NSObject)

```
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *myImageName;
```

and your PlayersViewController has an init method with an Object:

```
-(id) initWithObject:(YourObject *)object{
self=[super init];
if (self) {
    name=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
    name.text=object.name;
    [self.view addSubview:name];

    myImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200, 200, 200)];
    myImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:object.myImageName];
    [self.view addSubview:myImg];

}
return self;
}
```

This way is my way and I don't use storyboard and nib.
The other way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979976/ios-passing-data-to-pushed-viewcontroller)

I share my sample code :[sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By8m2_25-N5sYXVxRTJBU3hVV00/view?usp=sharing)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question! I can do the above when I use the presentViewController method but I lose data when I use [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES].

Comment: it's because when you push the new controller to navigation  stack the first controller will be lost so your datas will be gone. To avoid this, keep these datas on NSObject level.